# Integration business central and sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, azure-functions, power-automate, dynamics-business-central

I would like to add a checkbox or button in Business Central (Cloud), which makes it possible to automatically create a SharePoint Online Site.

I was thinking about using Azure functions or flow/logic apps, but I don't know if it's possible to create a trigger in Business Central. Does anyone have any experiences or recommendations?

This seems to answer a part of the question, but I am still wondering how to create the trigger in BC.

https://www.stadlersoftware.com/microsoft-flow/sharepoint-online-site-creation-using-microsoft-flow-and-azure-functions/

Answer (score 0):

You would need to develop an extension for Business Central and submit it to AppSource. There is an extensive guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/).

Another approach you could take is to trigger a Power Automate Flow or a Logic Apps when a record is created in Business Central. That way you won't need to modify Business Central it self.

There is in fact a [template for creating an item in SharePoint when a record is created in Business Central](https://flow.microsoft.com/da-dk/galleries/public/templates/9ab5f3faab684fb2aba256cf85252b74/create-an-item-in-sharepoint-when-a-record-is-created-in-business-central/).